# How to force Rpi to use usb soundcard

Tags: audio

I have RPi with usb soundcard
I have follow this answer
[USB card as my default Audio Device](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/usb-card-as-my-default-audio-device)
But i still can't make it work the settings always changing itself and i can't set my default soundcard to my usbsoundcard

there is no sound if I put my speaker to the usb soundcard
but it have when I put it to default rapsberry 3.5mm jack out

I test it via aplay

my lsub

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
```

my alsa-base.conf

```
# Keep snd-pcsp from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd_bcm2835 index=1
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
```

aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

*update*
It seems like my rpi won't produce sound if I remove my usb sound card
when I remove my usb sound card I can't execute amixer/alsamixer it returns cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

Comment: no long use on PIZERO! now https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39187/alsa-base-conf-file-missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so today i can make my rpi to use the usb soundcard
the workaround is

Reinstall my rapsbian with noobs
uncomment one line in alsa-base.conf

```
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
# options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

and
never ever go to GUI/startx
(I'm not sure about this one but when i run startx the amixer settings is changing itself)

now the aplay and arecord working flawlessy

Answer (score 1):

The trick is is in `~/.asoundrc`

If you have already gone into `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and changed `options snd-usb-audio index=-2` to `options snd-usb-audio index=0` then:

**First:**

`sudo nano ~/.asoundrc`

**Second:**

Add

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

Then save and reboot your Pi.

This works because when you add `options snd-usb-audio index=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` it only sets your usb card at index 0, it doesn't enable it.

Cheers!

Comment: why when i change the value to 1 when i reboot it always get back to 0, i have remove my settings in alsa-base.conf

Answer (score 0):

I have read idea about sound card. May be help u.
[Pi 2 Design](http://ubuntu4u.info/sound-card-raspberry-pi-hybrid-tube-amp/) is excited to introduce the first Tube Amp specifically designed for any of the 40-pin versions of the Raspberry Pi SBC Family. The 503HTA Hybrid Tube Amp HAT, designed and manufactured by Pi2Media (a division of PI 2 Design), is a High Quality I/O Shield designed to bring “Sweet Tube Sound” to the Raspberry PI ® family of Single Board Computers. This HAT allows the Raspberry Pi ® SBC to drive Headphones from 32 – 300 ohm with ease and fidelity.

Based on the popular Bravo V2 design with all recommended Mods, the On-Board PCM5102A DAC drives the single stage 12AU7 (or 6922) tube. The Class-A Output Stage is comprised of the IRL510 and LM317A. The dedicated heater supply insures zero crosstalk.
Source: http://ubuntu4u.info