# alsa-base conf file missing

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, alsa, pi-b+

I have a USB sound card for my pi b+ which I want to setup as my default sound device and all the tutorials for setting up involve editing the alsa-base.conf file in /etc/modeprobe.d, but I don't seem to have that file! Anyone able to help? I can see the usb fine when i run lsusb, and alsamixer detects it and plays audio fine. I'm running raspbian Jessie.

This is the USB sound card I'm using:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003UR9B8M?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00

Comment: What OS and distro are you using? If ausio is playing fne what is the problem?

Comment: Running Jessie, and i want to set it up so that the usb is the default audio loaded at startup. I'm following this tutorial: http://lifehacker.com/5978594/turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-an-airplay-receiver-for-streaming-music-in-your-living-room

Comment: Instead of putting important details in the comments please edit your question and add them there. The problem may be that the tutorial was designed for wheezy (based on the date it was posteed).

Comment: Edit completed. Do you know what the Jessie equivalent would be then? Or how do I go about setting up the default sound output on Jessie if the alsa-base.conf file is no longer there?

Comment: You should include that your issue is how to make it the default device. No I do not know the answer, but my comments and your edits will hopefully allow others to answer your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out the file is now called alsa.conf and is found in /usr/share/alsa.
Changed the lines

```
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
```

to card 1 and that's me up and running. Looks like others have different problems with other sound cards so worth looking at other solutions too. Found some good suggestions (including my solution) here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=124016&p=857433&hilit=alsa#p857433