# Unable to set default input and output audio device on Raspberry jessie

Tags: audio

I am facing a similar problem as described in this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/usb-card-as-my-default-audio-device). However I am running Jessie on Raspberry Pi and that it does not have a `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file.

So can someone tell me where and how to set the default input and output audio device on Jessie.

Comment: You could just try creating that file; I don't know if it was removed because of something to do with device tree, and if so whether that will make any difference.  What they are called actually doesn't matter (beyond determining the order in which they  are read), as long as they end in `.conf`.  It's what's in them that counts.

Comment: ok I will create it but then what will the contents of the same. Should I add just one line "options snd-usb-audio index=0" ??

Comment: I think there are two lines suggested there, that one and `options snd_bcm2835 index=1`.

Comment: Hi i tried adding the same but still the default is the snd_bcm2835 only. I also did a reboot

Comment: Leave that there, and if you aren't using device tree for anything (e.g. I2C), try adding `device_tree=` (with nothing after it) in `/boot/config.txt` to disable it, then reboot again.  If that doesn't work, you might as well remove that line from `config.txt` so you do not forget later.

Comment: "Jessie" will be using `systemd` as its "init" by default; pulseaudio is a separate thing to Alsa, and systemd and pulseaudio share the same "[Father](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennart_Poettering)" so I suspect that if PA is around systemd will be interacting with it.  I may however be acting as a FUD-merchant here... 8-P

Comment: Please see [my writeup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/80072/how-can-i-use-an-external-usb-sound-card-and-set-it-as-default) for further details and solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, first delete the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` Raspbian Jessie does not use this config file like Wheezy did.

To find what address your device uses you need to first enter the command `aplay -l` this shows all audio output devices, and their address. For example, my USB sound card comes up as device 1 in the output which looks like this.

```
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Now, to set the device to your default card you will need to edit the file `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` with the command `sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` scroll down until you find the lines

```
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
```

and change them to (if your device is also listed as device 1, if not change the 1 to whatever address it was listed at)

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

Explanation: USB sound cards are registered as card 1 on Raspbian Jessie. On Wheezy they would be registered as card -2 by default and editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` would change that.

I do not know if this next step is necessary but without it my card wouldn't work.

Create and edit the file `~/.asoundrc` by using the command `sudo nano ~/.asoundrc` and change it so that it only reads this:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

Now your default audio out (speakers) and audio in (mic) are your usb device.

Comment: @ParthDoshi I edited the question, in case you aren't using a USB sound card.

Comment: thanks Patrick for the quick reply. I will check this and let you know. I am using a USB mic as input and audio speakers as output. My speakers are connected via a 3.5 mm audio jack.

Comment: @ParthDoshi so your speakers are using the standard sound card on the pi?

Comment: yes they are using the standard sound card. I did a test by running the speaker-test command...I am able to play a sample mp3 file on my PI that I can hear via my speakers clearly, The only problem is the mic as of now

Comment: Ok, then you do not need to change one of the lines in those files, I'm figuring out which line right now.

Comment: @DarthPoshi Never mind, you still need to edit both lines for the card to work, but it will set your default audio output to that card as well.

Comment: @DarthPoshi you can keep the USB mic as the standard input/output and use `--device=hw:0,0` to your `aplay` commands assuming you're using `aplay` for all audio. Or you can leave the Pi's sound card as the default card and add `--device=hw:1,0` to all `arecord` commands, assuming you're using `arecord` for all of your recordings. There's no easy way that I know of to use one sound card as input and another as output.

Comment: Thanks it worked! :) If you have the time, can you please look at this question too? http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39940/how-to-resolve-invalid-sample-rate-9997

Comment: @ParthDoshi Yah sure, no problem

Comment: Per [user's](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/22193/edoardo-ceccarelli) edit: *There is no need to change ALSA library configuration file, everything just works by creating ~/.asoundrc as instructed (btw thank you, I would comment but I don't have reputation)* (edit had to be rejected as clearly conflicting with authors intent)

Comment: Is this the same for Buster?

Answer (score 5):

Question is referring to another post which has already an [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/44825/22193) that simply states that with Jessie there is no need to edit `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`, just create `~/.asoundrc` and type in

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

PS: I just tested it with a clean installation on a raspberry 2 connected with Logitech Z-5 speakers, works perfectly

Comment: I followed your answer and done reboot but when I use Audacity with selected "default" in/output no audio captured and should choose "Loopback PCM hw:0,0" & "Loopback PCM hw:0,1" as my virtual sound card index is 0. Is there another configuration needed for Apps?

Comment: @MamdouhSaeed you should probably play with `device` index option as other answers are pointing out. I must say since 2016 audio configuration on the raspberry has gotten more complicated in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a different device for input and output (e.g. usb mikrophone and 3.5mm audio speaker), you can write it like this in your ~/.asoundrc:

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  playback.pcm
  {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
  }
  capture.pcm
  {
    type hw
    card 1
    device 0
  }
}
```