# How to resolve Invalid sample rate -9997

Tags: audio

I am trying to install Jasper on my Raspberry Pi model B running Jessie distro.

I have followed the installation guide. However, when I am now trying to run the the program I am getting the following error

```
root@raspberrypi:/karan/jasper/boot# ./boot.sh

elf.mic.passiveListen(self.persona) File "/karan/jasper/client/mic.py", line 110, in passiveListen frames_per_buffer=CHUNK) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open stream = Stream(self, args, *kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init self._stream = pa.open(**arguments) IOError: [Errno Invalid sample rate] -9997
```

I have a USB microphone connected to my Pi
Can someone please help solve this issue?

Comment: I haven't looked into Jasper's code much, but I remember I had a very similar problem when I first started Nano. Can you look into the code and see what commands Jasper uses for recording and speech recognition? The recording sample rate must match the sample rate of the recognition which is usually 48000.

Comment: ohh I understand. I will check and post the the sample rate value for jasper from my code. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: hi @PatrickCook: I checked the sample rate. It is RATE = 16000. Can you please have a look at this file https://github.com/jasperproject/jasper-client/blob/master/client/mic.py

Comment: Try having a look at this post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=97702 it is the exact same problem and the person believes to have found a fix.

Comment: Are you able to record? What is the message you get when you do: "arecord temp.wav"? Also if you can paste the output of "arecord -L" and "cat /proc/asound/modules" I maybe able to help you. Cheers.