# noob trying to get his usb audio to stay as default

Tags: audio

I have edited this with hopes of being more clear.

I got my card working thanks to this site, and this question / answer:
 [Unable to set default input and output audio device on Raspberry jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39928/unable-to-set-default-input-and-output-audio-device-on-raspberry-jessie)

In the answer the first instruction is to delete:
    /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
I wasn't sure how to do this; if I needed to use an editor, or I could delete text from the terminal

I entered   **sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf** in a terminal and found it to be empty. I did not delete it, and am still unsure how I should go about doing so.
The next instruction is to enter the command `aplay -l`
I did so and my card is there:

```
 card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
 card 1: USB [Scarlett 2i2 USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The next instruction was to edit the file `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf`
I did so, and it currently reads:

```
  defaults.ctl.card 1
  defaults.pcm.card 1
```

then I hit ctrl x to exit, Y for yes' to save changes and then enter.

The next instruction was to Create and edit the file `~/.asoundrc`
I did so to read:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

then I hit crl X, then y for yes and then enter,
 is this the right way?

Everything works as it should until the next start up, and the default card returns to 0 within the `~/.asoundrc`file only.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may compile ALSA by hand and it will use `/etc`-located system-wide config for sure, and there you can set all the things you need. Another approach is to use UDEV/usb-plugging rule to forcibly enable and set your card as a default as soon as it is detected by the OS

Comment: Thanks Alexy, I will look into those options. I was editing my question while you answered, sorry about that. I am over my head at the moment, but I will learn.

Comment: @EdwardBate this is a common situation/problem with "Debianized" packages. IMHO it's questionable to divert packet's behaviour such weird, so use a source compilation : you'll have latest patches in it and the standard behaviour, no surprises like that